# Custom Links menu items include in Search Results

Tags: menus, search, links

Wrote this function to display the menu items into search, it is working, on search it includes the menu items but the link to them is not correct, by default search items contain link to Permalink/slug

There are some external links in menu items so i want the links to be included correctly,

```
 function my_multisite_search($query) {
    if(!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search) {
        $query->set('multisite', 1);
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'attachment', 'nav_menu_item'));
        $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish', 'inherit' ) );

    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_multisite_search');
```

Comment: Are you using WordPress Multi-site ?

Comment: @Nestsouls, Yes, but i think that should not effect the search behavior.